# webpack 4 react build causes token error, but run start works

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

After a build with webpack I am getting the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token error.  I am able to run start and it will load that way.  So I know this must be a problem with the output, or so I would imagine.

The index.html is generating properly, as is the bundle.js.  I have that as a path on my index.html file. I am using webpack 4 and have the following webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports ={
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '8080'
      },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),

    ]
}
```

My .babelrc

```
    {
        "presets": [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
      }

Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Expensify</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
<body>
    <div id="src"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducer from './store/reducers/auth';

const composeEnhances = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhances(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

const app = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('src'));
```

Packages.json

```
{
  "name": "reactboilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React Webpack Redux Babel Boilerplate",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "author": "Thomas Baric",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "help": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your index.js and are you importing any css

Comment: I haven't made it to CSS lol.  I'll update with the index.js

Comment: is it `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token error <` and i mean the token is '<'

Comment: Yes, exactly.  
bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: your jsx is not being transformed to js. have you installed all the required packages

Comment: I will add my packages.json as well.

Comment: it looks fine but remove old  `"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0","babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",`  and try `npm i`

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  I don't have any .jsx files, do i still need that?

Comment: it's not needed

Comment: if it didn't work use `use: {loader: 'babel-loader'}` in rules in webpack.config instead of `loader: 'babel-loader'`

Comment: That didn't work either.  And I removed all the older babels as well

Comment: Looks good but ordering in rules might help you eg: `test, use, exclude` in webpack rules

Comment: Dude, I'm so sorry.  It was all about my backend.  I was using Django and didn't set up my static files correctly.  JS ENGINE IM SORRY BRO don't be mad

Comment: One last question, is it possible to output the index.html in a different spot?

Comment: it's ok.  And it is possibe but have not tried it.

Comment: Once again dude, appreciate you puttin up with me tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering this was a backend Django problem regarding static files.  Here is my working webpack and babel.  This does work on heroku.  https://djreactboilertest.herokuapp.com

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports ={
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'static'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: {loader: 'babel-loader'},
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '8080'
      },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),

    ]
}

{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-class-properties",
      ["transform-object-rest-spread", { "useBuiltIns": true }]

    ]
  }
```